# unable to Login to Admin

Tags: login

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'no_wordpress_errors' not found or invalid function name in /home/cafereminiscence/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 235

Comment: `no_wordpress_errors` isn't a core function, probably a plugin or theme issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error happens during the loading of the plugin.php core code, it is probably an error with a plugin that is trying to be loaded.

I'd do a text search of all plugin folder files for the string 'no_wordpress_error'. Wherever that is, that's the plugin that is probably causing the problem.  Rename that plugin's folder, and try the site again.

If you verify that a plugin is causing the problem, then you should contact the plugin's support area (not here, since plugin support here is not supported).

If you don't find that string in the plugin folders' files, then do the same search in your themes folder. It ought to be in one of those two places (I'd suspect the plugin folder more).